# Multivariate Bayes' Rule

Tags: probability

I want to answer a question that's basically like this: there are multiple variables (forecast, temperature, humidity and wind), and you have the information about if you can play football in a given day, according to the weather. Image below:
[image]

What's the probability of playing tennis in any given circumstances? Should I apply Bayes' Rule multiple times to arrive at the probability? Is there a procedure I can follow to find the answer? In other words, $$P(\text{not playing football} | f, T, h, w)=?$$

Comment: This seems like a straight frequency question, no? Just count the cases.  There is no (apparent) underlying model here.

Comment: really? So what if I want to, for example, find out whether I'll play when it's sunny, cold, humid and windy? This particular case doesn't appear in the list. Is the probability zero then?

Comment: Well, you can't answer that question from the data.

Comment: Nothing stops you from building a model, of course, though you have essentially no data to work with here so it would all be guesswork.  Keep in mind:  data is not magic.  All data tells you is what was observed.  If you want information about things that were not observed, you'll need a model connecting the unobserved things to the observed things.

Comment: Should add:  given how thin the data is, I wouldn't even put much faith in the frequentist computation I cited in my first comment.  In real life, there's probably a couple of people making a call near game time and external variables (like who is on duty that day and such) are likely to be very important.